# Hashmap access and scope i get null always inside methods

Tags: java, android

I  am trying to add some data in hashmap i am declaring the hashmap as class field but am adding data to itcinside several methods and on a final method when i try to get the data i get null or empty as if data didn't exist inside hashmap here is a sample code of what am doing

```
Public myclass extens fragment {
Private Map<String, String> data = new 
hashmap<String,String>() ;

@override
Public onViewCreated() {
//some code
Return view;}

Public view stepOne() {
EditText text = findviewbyid(id) ;
String text1 = text. getText().toString();

data.put("data1",text1);

Return text;
}

Public view stepTwo(
{EditText text2 = findviewbyid(id) ;
String text3 = text. getText().toString();

data.put("data2",text3);

Return text2;}

Public view stepFinal() {
String firstStepData = data.get("data1");

String firstStepData = data.get("data2");
}
}
```

The variables in stepFinal() are empty why and how can i approach this?

Comment: Can you please show the code from which you are using methods of this class?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same key (the first parameter when using map.put(key, value) to get value from Map

Like
      //instead of text1 use data1 as key
     String firstStepData = data.get("data1");

In your code you are trying to get value from map using value you inserted instead of key ("text1" instead of "data1") 
 Please refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java/) or refer any other tutorial on net for more understanding..

Comment: sorry that was a mistake i already made it correct but it is not the problem i am facing

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your variable, use HashMap instead of Map.
Then, check better how hashmap works in this [link](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/).

Quick explanation:

Hashmap works using key-value pairing, so, if you declare hashmap this way:

```
private HashMap<String,String>
```

You're saying that your hashmap has String as key and another String as value.
If you want to get some value, you should use the associated key:

```
data.put("myKey","myValue")
data.get("myKey")
```

In your case, you can get only the last value assigned to "data1" key because you overwrite that key in "stepTwo".

So, in step two you should use another key, for example:

```
data.put("data3","text3");
```

And in the finalStep:

```
data.get("data1");
data.get(""data3");
```

Comment: yes that was a mistake i didnt see it but it is not the problem the application works fine and everything is good but i get null values when using map.get("key");  is it because it is not possible to add values into hashmap inside a method and call them in another method ???

Comment: Obviously it's not so, it would have no sense to have a variable you cannot use, try to check if there's something in it using "containsKey" and "containsValue" methods and "isEmpty".
Then, you could try " private HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>(). You're way (using the interface Map) should works too, but give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the hashmap i wanted to store data into it to pass it through steps in a vertical stepper in android

i ended up using a signleton model to store data to it and call it again